Adding text with reference to yticklabel in polar plot
I have a polar plot with a not very clever dB label under yticklabel. In this case everything is fine, but I want to change many such charts but with a different y-range, so I need to add a label with references to yticklabel.
Code:
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{table/search path={dane}, compat=1.18}
\usepgfplotslibrary{polar}
%
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{polaraxis}[
            clip mode=individual,
            xticklabel=$\pgfmathprintnumber{\tick}^\circ$,
            xtick={0,30,...,330},
            ymin=0, ymax=45,
            y coord trafo/.code=\pgfmathparse{#1+0},
            rotate=-90,
            y coord inv trafo/.code=\pgfmathparse{#1-0},
            x dir=reverse,
            xticklabel style={anchor=-\tick-90},
            yticklabel style={anchor=east, xshift=-4.75cm},
            y axis line style={yshift=-4.75cm},
            ytick style={yshift=-4.75cm},
            grid=both,
            major grid style={dotted},  
            minor grid style={dotted},  
            minor x tick num=1,
            minor y tick num=1,
        ]
            \node at (85, -65) {dB};
            \addlegendentry{2.40 GHz}
            \addplot [no markers, thick, red] table [col sep=comma, y=Axial] {axial_iter2_frag_3_2400.csv}; 
        \end{polaraxis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
%
\end{document}


How can I solve this?
Data:
Dir,Phi,Axial,Cross,Coop
0,-26.46,25.8,4.929,-1.816
1,-26.53,28.62,4.913,-1.933
2,-26.6,32.82,4.894,-2.053
3,-26.68,40.0,4.872,-2.176
4,-26.76,40.0,4.847,-2.302
5,-26.85,34.2,4.819,-2.43
6,-26.94,29.49,4.787,-2.559
7,-27.04,26.47,4.753,-2.691
8,-27.15,24.24,4.715,-2.823
9,-27.26,22.48,4.674,-2.957
10,-27.37,21.02,4.629,-3.091
11,-27.49,19.79,4.581,-3.226
12,-27.62,18.71,4.53,-3.361
13,-27.75,17.76,4.476,-3.495
14,-27.89,16.91,4.418,-3.629
15,-28.03,16.15,4.356,-3.762
16,-28.18,15.45,4.292,-3.894
17,-28.33,14.81,4.223,-4.024
18,-28.49,14.23,4.152,-4.152
19,-28.65,13.69,4.077,-4.278
20,-28.82,13.19,3.998,-4.402
21,-28.99,12.72,3.916,-4.523
22,-29.17,12.28,3.83,-4.642
23,-29.36,11.88,3.741,-4.757
24,-29.55,11.5,3.649,-4.87
25,-29.74,11.15,3.552,-4.979
26,-29.94,10.81,3.453,-5.085
27,-30.15,10.5,3.35,-5.188
28,-30.36,10.21,3.243,-5.287
29,-30.58,9.941,3.134,-5.384
30,-30.8,9.687,3.02,-5.477
31,-31.03,9.451,2.903,-5.567
32,-31.26,9.23,2.783,-5.655
33,-31.5,9.026,2.66,-5.74
34,-31.74,8.836,2.533,-5.822
35,-31.99,8.662,2.403,-5.902
36,-32.24,8.501,2.269,-5.979
37,-32.5,8.355,2.133,-6.055
38,-32.76,8.222,1.993,-6.129
39,-33.02,8.102,1.85,-6.202
40,-33.3,7.995,1.704,-6.273
41,-33.57,7.901,1.555,-6.344
42,-33.85,7.819,1.404,-6.413
43,-34.14,7.749,1.249,-6.482
44,-34.43,7.69,1.091,-6.551
45,-34.72,7.643,0.9308,-6.619
46,-35.02,7.607,0.7678,-6.688
47,-35.32,7.581,0.6021,-6.757
48,-35.62,7.566,0.434,-6.826
49,-35.93,7.561,0.2634,-6.896
50,-36.25,7.565,0.09044,-6.966
51,-36.56,7.579,-0.08474,-7.037
52,-36.88,7.602,-0.2621,-7.109
53,-37.2,7.633,-0.4414,-7.182
54,-37.53,7.672,-0.6227,-7.255
55,-37.85,7.719,-0.8058,-7.33
56,-38.18,7.774,-0.9905,-7.406
57,-38.52,7.835,-1.177,-7.484
58,-38.85,7.903,-1.365,-7.562
59,-39.18,7.977,-1.554,-7.642
60,-39.52,8.056,-1.744,-7.722
61,-39.86,8.141,-1.935,-7.804
62,-40.2,8.23,-2.127,-7.887
63,-40.54,8.323,-2.32,-7.971
64,-40.88,8.421,-2.513,-8.056
65,-41.22,8.521,-2.707,-8.142
66,-41.56,8.624,-2.901,-8.228
67,-41.9,8.73,-3.095,-8.316
68,-42.23,8.837,-3.289,-8.404
69,-42.57,8.945,-3.483,-8.492
70,-42.91,9.054,-3.676,-8.581
71,-43.24,9.163,-3.868,-8.67
72,-43.57,9.271,-4.06,-8.759
73,-43.9,9.377,-4.251,-8.848
74,-44.23,9.482,-4.441,-8.937
75,-44.55,9.583,-4.629,-9.025
76,-44.87,9.681,-4.816,-9.113
77,-45.19,9.775,-5.001,-9.2
78,-45.5,9.863,-5.185,-9.285
79,-45.81,9.946,-5.366,-9.37
80,-46.12,10.02,-5.546,-9.453
81,-46.41,10.09,-5.723,-9.534
82,-46.71,10.15,-5.899,-9.613
83,-47.0,10.2,-6.071,-9.69
84,-47.28,10.24,-6.242,-9.765
85,-47.55,10.27,-6.409,-9.837
86,-47.82,10.29,-6.575,-9.906
87,-48.09,10.3,-6.737,-9.972
88,-48.34,10.3,-6.897,-10.03
89,-48.59,10.28,-7.055,-10.09
90,-48.84,10.25,-7.209,-10.15
91,-49.07,10.21,-7.361,-10.2
92,-49.3,10.15,-7.511,-10.25
93,-49.52,10.08,-7.657,-10.29
94,-49.73,9.996,-7.802,-10.33
95,-49.94,9.898,-7.944,-10.36
96,-50.14,9.788,-8.083,-10.39
97,-50.33,9.664,-8.221,-10.41
98,-50.51,9.529,-8.356,-10.43
99,-50.68,9.381,-8.49,-10.44
100,-50.85,9.222,-8.622,-10.45
101,-51.01,9.053,-8.752,-10.45
102,-51.16,8.874,-8.881,-10.45
103,-51.3,8.686,-9.008,-10.45
104,-51.44,8.489,-9.134,-10.43
105,-51.57,8.285,-9.259,-10.42
106,-51.69,8.074,-9.384,-10.4
107,-51.81,7.857,-9.507,-10.38
108,-51.92,7.636,-9.63,-10.35
109,-52.02,7.409,-9.753,-10.32
110,-52.12,7.18,-9.876,-10.28
111,-52.21,6.948,-9.998,-10.24
112,-52.29,6.714,-10.12,-10.2
113,-52.37,6.479,-10.24,-10.16
114,-52.45,6.244,-10.37,-10.12
115,-52.52,6.009,-10.49,-10.07
116,-52.58,5.776,-10.61,-10.02
117,-52.64,5.546,-10.74,-9.973
118,-52.7,5.319,-10.86,-9.924
119,-52.76,5.096,-10.99,-9.875
120,-52.81,4.879,-11.11,-9.826
121,-52.86,4.669,-11.24,-9.778
122,-52.91,4.468,-11.36,-9.731
123,-52.96,4.276,-11.49,-9.686
124,-53.0,4.096,-11.61,-9.642
125,-53.05,3.93,-11.74,-9.601
126,-53.09,3.78,-11.86,-9.563
127,-53.14,3.648,-11.99,-9.527
128,-53.19,3.537,-12.11,-9.496
129,-53.24,3.449,-12.23,-9.468
130,-53.29,3.387,-12.35,-9.444
131,-53.34,3.353,-12.47,-9.424
132,-53.4,3.348,-12.59,-9.41
133,-53.46,3.373,-12.7,-9.401
134,-53.52,3.43,-12.81,-9.398
135,-53.59,3.516,-12.92,-9.401
136,-53.67,3.633,-13.02,-9.41
137,-53.75,3.777,-13.12,-9.426
138,-53.84,3.949,-13.21,-9.449
139,-53.93,4.146,-13.29,-9.48
140,-54.03,4.366,-13.37,-9.519
141,-54.14,4.61,-13.45,-9.566
142,-54.26,4.876,-13.51,-9.622
143,-54.39,5.164,-13.57,-9.688
144,-54.52,5.473,-13.62,-9.763
145,-54.67,5.804,-13.67,-9.848
146,-54.83,6.158,-13.7,-9.944
147,-54.99,6.535,-13.73,-10.05
148,-55.17,6.936,-13.75,-10.17
149,-55.36,7.365,-13.76,-10.3
150,-55.56,7.823,-13.76,-10.45
151,-55.77,8.314,-13.75,-10.61
152,-55.99,8.842,-13.74,-10.78
153,-56.23,9.412,-13.72,-10.97
154,-56.47,10.03,-13.69,-11.17
155,-56.72,10.7,-13.66,-11.39
156,-56.99,11.44,-13.61,-11.63
157,-57.26,12.26,-13.57,-11.89
158,-57.55,13.17,-13.51,-12.17
159,-57.84,14.21,-13.45,-12.47
160,-58.14,15.39,-13.39,-12.8
161,-58.44,16.76,-13.32,-13.15
162,-58.74,18.41,-13.24,-13.53
163,-59.04,20.43,-13.17,-13.94
164,-59.34,23.04,-13.08,-14.39
165,-59.64,26.73,-13.0,-14.87
166,-59.92,33.03,-12.91,-15.4
167,-60.2,40.0,-12.82,-15.97
168,-60.45,33.14,-12.72,-16.6
169,-60.69,27.57,-12.63,-17.28
170,-60.89,24.53,-12.53,-18.04
171,-61.07,22.59,-12.43,-18.89
172,-61.21,21.34,-12.32,-19.84
173,-61.32,20.59,-12.22,-20.92
174,-61.39,20.26,-12.11,-22.16
175,-61.41,20.33,-12.0,-23.61
176,-61.38,20.81,-11.89,-25.37
177,-61.31,21.75,-11.78,-27.56
178,-61.2,23.29,-11.66,-30.48
179,-61.04,25.72,-11.55,-34.72
180,-60.85,29.86,-11.43,-41.24
181,-60.61,39.77,-11.32,-39.75
182,-60.34,37.49,-11.2,-33.73
183,-60.04,28.37,-11.08,-29.91
184,-59.72,23.92,-10.96,-27.25
185,-59.37,20.96,-10.85,-25.22
186,-59.01,18.75,-10.73,-23.6
187,-58.63,17.01,-10.61,-22.25
188,-58.25,15.59,-10.49,-21.1
189,-57.86,14.4,-10.37,-20.11
190,-57.47,13.38,-10.26,-19.25
191,-57.08,12.5,-10.14,-18.48
192,-56.69,11.74,-10.02,-17.79
193,-56.31,11.07,-9.909,-17.18
194,-55.94,10.47,-9.796,-16.63
195,-55.58,9.949,-9.683,-16.12
196,-55.22,9.483,-9.571,-15.67
197,-54.88,9.068,-9.461,-15.26
198,-54.55,8.7,-9.353,-14.88
199,-54.23,8.373,-9.246,-14.54
200,-53.93,8.084,-9.14,-14.23
201,-53.63,7.828,-9.037,-13.95
202,-53.35,7.604,-8.935,-13.7
203,-53.09,7.409,-8.834,-13.47
204,-52.83,7.241,-8.736,-13.26
205,-52.59,7.1,-8.639,-13.07
206,-52.37,6.982,-8.543,-12.91
207,-52.15,6.888,-8.45,-12.76
208,-51.95,6.817,-8.358,-12.64
209,-51.76,6.767,-8.268,-12.53
210,-51.58,6.739,-8.179,-12.43
211,-51.41,6.731,-8.092,-12.35
212,-51.25,6.743,-8.006,-12.29
213,-51.1,6.776,-7.921,-12.24
214,-50.96,6.828,-7.838,-12.21
215,-50.83,6.9,-7.755,-12.19
216,-50.7,6.992,-7.674,-12.18
217,-50.58,7.103,-7.594,-12.18
218,-50.47,7.234,-7.514,-12.2
219,-50.37,7.386,-7.435,-12.23
220,-50.27,7.557,-7.356,-12.26
221,-50.17,7.75,-7.278,-12.31
222,-50.08,7.964,-7.2,-12.37
223,-49.99,8.2,-7.122,-12.43
224,-49.9,8.458,-7.044,-12.51
225,-49.82,8.74,-6.966,-12.59
226,-49.73,9.046,-6.887,-12.68
227,-49.65,9.379,-6.808,-12.78
228,-49.56,9.739,-6.729,-12.88
229,-49.47,10.13,-6.649,-12.99
230,-49.38,10.55,-6.568,-13.1
231,-49.29,11.0,-6.487,-13.21
232,-49.19,11.49,-6.405,-13.33
233,-49.09,12.02,-6.321,-13.44
234,-48.99,12.6,-6.237,-13.56
235,-48.88,13.23,-6.151,-13.67
236,-48.76,13.91,-6.064,-13.78
237,-48.64,14.66,-5.976,-13.88
238,-48.51,15.49,-5.887,-13.98
239,-48.37,16.41,-5.796,-14.06
240,-48.23,17.45,-5.704,-14.13
241,-48.08,18.63,-5.611,-14.19
242,-47.93,19.99,-5.516,-14.24
243,-47.76,21.61,-5.419,-14.27
244,-47.59,23.59,-5.321,-14.28
245,-47.41,26.15,-5.222,-14.27
246,-47.23,29.78,-5.121,-14.24
247,-47.04,36.05,-5.019,-14.2
248,-46.84,40.0,-4.915,-14.13
249,-46.63,35.29,-4.81,-14.04
250,-46.41,29.51,-4.704,-13.93
251,-46.19,26.1,-4.596,-13.8
252,-45.97,23.69,-4.487,-13.65
253,-45.74,21.82,-4.376,-13.49
254,-45.5,20.3,-4.265,-13.31
255,-45.25,19.03,-4.152,-13.11
256,-45.01,17.93,-4.038,-12.91
257,-44.75,16.97,-3.923,-12.69
258,-44.49,16.12,-3.806,-12.47
259,-44.23,15.36,-3.689,-12.24
260,-43.96,14.67,-3.571,-12.0
261,-43.69,14.04,-3.452,-11.75
262,-43.42,13.46,-3.331,-11.5
263,-43.14,12.93,-3.211,-11.25
264,-42.86,12.43,-3.089,-11.0
265,-42.58,11.97,-2.966,-10.75
266,-42.3,11.55,-2.843,-10.49
267,-42.01,11.14,-2.719,-10.24
268,-41.72,10.77,-2.595,-9.983
269,-41.43,10.41,-2.47,-9.73
270,-41.14,10.07,-2.344,-9.479
271,-40.85,9.756,-2.219,-9.23
272,-40.56,9.454,-2.092,-8.982
273,-40.26,9.168,-1.966,-8.737
274,-39.97,8.895,-1.839,-8.495
275,-39.67,8.635,-1.712,-8.255
276,-39.38,8.386,-1.585,-8.018
277,-39.08,8.149,-1.457,-7.784
278,-38.79,7.921,-1.33,-7.552
279,-38.5,7.703,-1.202,-7.324
280,-38.2,7.494,-1.075,-7.099
281,-37.91,7.293,-0.9478,-6.877
282,-37.62,7.101,-0.8206,-6.658
283,-37.33,6.915,-0.6937,-6.442
284,-37.04,6.737,-0.567,-6.229
285,-36.75,6.566,-0.4407,-6.019
286,-36.46,6.401,-0.3147,-5.813
287,-36.17,6.243,-0.1891,-5.61
288,-35.89,6.091,-0.06398,-5.41
289,-35.61,5.945,0.06061,-5.213
290,-35.33,5.805,0.1846,-5.02
291,-35.05,5.671,0.308,-4.83
292,-34.78,5.543,0.4307,-4.643
293,-34.5,5.421,0.5527,-4.46
294,-34.23,5.305,0.6739,-4.28
295,-33.96,5.195,0.7943,-4.103
296,-33.7,5.091,0.9138,-3.93
297,-33.44,4.993,1.032,-3.76
298,-33.18,4.903,1.15,-3.594
299,-32.92,4.819,1.266,-3.431
300,-32.67,4.742,1.382,-3.271
301,-32.42,4.672,1.496,-3.116
302,-32.17,4.61,1.609,-2.963
303,-31.93,4.555,1.721,-2.815
304,-31.69,4.509,1.832,-2.67
305,-31.45,4.471,1.941,-2.529
306,-31.22,4.442,2.049,-2.392
307,-30.99,4.422,2.156,-2.258
308,-30.77,4.411,2.261,-2.129
309,-30.55,4.409,2.364,-2.003
310,-30.34,4.418,2.466,-1.882
311,-30.13,4.436,2.567,-1.764
312,-29.92,4.464,2.666,-1.651
313,-29.72,4.503,2.763,-1.542
314,-29.52,4.552,2.859,-1.437
315,-29.33,4.611,2.953,-1.336
316,-29.15,4.68,3.045,-1.239
317,-28.96,4.76,3.135,-1.147
318,-28.79,4.851,3.223,-1.06
319,-28.62,4.951,3.31,-0.9767
320,-28.45,5.062,3.395,-0.8982
321,-28.29,5.183,3.477,-0.8243
322,-28.13,5.315,3.558,-0.755
323,-27.98,5.456,3.637,-0.6904
324,-27.84,5.608,3.714,-0.6306
325,-27.7,5.77,3.789,-0.5756
326,-27.57,5.942,3.862,-0.5254
327,-27.44,6.124,3.932,-0.4802
328,-27.32,6.317,4.001,-0.4399
329,-27.2,6.52,4.067,-0.4046
330,-27.09,6.733,4.132,-0.3743
331,-26.99,6.958,4.194,-0.3491
332,-26.89,7.194,4.253,-0.3289
333,-26.79,7.441,4.311,-0.3139
334,-26.71,7.7,4.366,-0.3041
335,-26.62,7.972,4.42,-0.2994
336,-26.55,8.256,4.47,-0.2999
337,-26.48,8.554,4.519,-0.3056
338,-26.41,8.867,4.565,-0.3166
339,-26.36,9.194,4.609,-0.3327
340,-26.3,9.538,4.65,-0.3541
341,-26.26,9.899,4.689,-0.3807
342,-26.22,10.28,4.725,-0.4125
343,-26.18,10.68,4.759,-0.4496
344,-26.15,11.1,4.791,-0.4917
345,-26.13,11.55,4.82,-0.5391
346,-26.11,12.02,4.846,-0.5915
347,-26.1,12.52,4.87,-0.6489
348,-26.09,13.05,4.891,-0.7114
349,-26.09,13.63,4.909,-0.7788
350,-26.1,14.24,4.925,-0.851
351,-26.11,14.9,4.938,-0.928
352,-26.13,15.62,4.948,-1.01
353,-26.15,16.4,4.956,-1.096
354,-26.18,17.26,4.961,-1.187
355,-26.21,18.22,4.963,-1.282
356,-26.25,19.3,4.962,-1.381
357,-26.3,20.53,4.958,-1.484
358,-26.35,21.96,4.951,-1.591
359,-26.4,23.67,4.941,-1.701
360,-26.46,25.8,4.929,-1.816


Please copy your csv-file (as code), perhaps with fewer data points, so we can test your code. // So you want to have: a) identical plots, b) with different data, c) with different (short) legend text (like frequencies)?

I can change the plot for other data. My question concerns the text box 'dB'. In my example, the node depends on the maximum value of yticks. I want to add this label standalone.

Ok: you want to have different units, like dBnV or cm? Or change the range? Please clarify, perhaps by example. Thank you

@MS-SPO just add text for example 'dB' or 'dBi' that is located independent from y- range (now is constant value from (0,0) polar plot, when i change y-range i have to change also value in \node at (85, -65) {dB};

Thank you. Please add your (simplified) data file ...

@MS-SPO here is my data file: https://justpaste.it/cxayz

Thank you. Please read more carefully, also comments. External links tend to disappear and impose other problems. So, with this message over my comment box: bye. "Please avoid extended discussions in comments. Would you like to automatically move this discussion to chat?"

Please see my update, below. Looks like your transformations contribute to the trouble.

There may be a way to retrieve the ylabels node, which would be best to do, e.g. to use anchoring. If it's there, it's pretty hidden in the manual.
However, please see below a few ways to put nodes on your polaraxis plot. Please note, that the cs-coordinates are given as polar coordinates, thouch a comma ,  is used as separator.
Also the polar-axis may be somewhat special, as you can think of a rotated beam around the blue X.

\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{table/search path={dane}, compat=1.18}
\usepgfplotslibrary{polar}
%
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{polaraxis}[
            clip mode=individual,
            xticklabel=$\pgfmathprintnumber{\tick}^\circ$,
            xtick={0,30,...,330},
            ymin=0, ymax=45,
            y coord trafo/.code=\pgfmathparse{#1+0},
            rotate=-90,
            y coord inv trafo/.code=\pgfmathparse{#1-0},
            x dir=reverse,
            xticklabel style={anchor=-\tick-90},
            yticklabel style={anchor=east, xshift=-4.75cm},
            y axis line style={yshift=-4.75cm},
            ytick style={yshift=-4.75cm},
            grid=both,
            major grid style={dotted},  
            minor grid style={dotted},  
            minor x tick num=1,
            minor y tick num=1,
        ]
            % ~~~ your approach ~~~~~~~
            \node at (85, -65) {dB};
            % ~~~ using the axis' coordinate system ~~~~~~~
            \node[teal] at (axis cs:270,45) {X};
            \node[blue] at (axis cs:0,0) {X};
            \addplot [no markers, 
                      thick, red] table [col sep=comma, y=Axial] 
                      {datap.dat};
            \addlegendentry{2.40 GHz}
            % ~~~ simple, but intermingled with your shifts above ~~~
            \node[teal] at (axis cs:260,63) {Y};
        \end{polaraxis}
        
        % ~~~ could have worked ... but doesn't ~~~~~~~~~~~
        \node[anchor=north west] at (current axis) {Test};

    \end{tikzpicture}
%
\end{document}


P.S.: BTW, this happens, when you switch from polaraxis to axis. If you follow the various nodes/labels, you see why axis coordinates (axis cs:) have advantages.


UPDATE
The following code holds some more analysis. Key questions:

how are the relationships between cartesian and polar view here?
is there some node we can anchor to?
which ones will be robust, i.e. most invariant, i.e. least sensitive to changes?

Ok, first the code, second some compiles.
%\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\documentclass[10pt,border=3mm,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{table/search path={dane}, compat=1.18}
\usepgfplotslibrary{polar}
%
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
        pt/.style={purple,circle,draw}, 
    ]
        \begin{axis}[
            clip mode=individual,
            xticklabel=$\pgfmathprintnumber{\tick}^\circ$,
            xtick={0,30,...,330},
            ymin=0, ymax=45,
            % ~~~ the next 4 lines are part of the trouble ~~~
            y coord trafo/.code=\pgfmathparse{#1+0},
            rotate=-90,
            y coord inv trafo/.code=\pgfmathparse{#1-0},
            x dir=reverse,
            % ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
            xticklabel style={anchor=-\tick-90},
            %
            % ~~~ what, if you can name something? ~~~
            yticklabel style={anchor=east, xshift=-4.75cm,name=A},% p.376
            y axis line style={yshift=-4.75cm},
            ytick style={yshift=-4.75cm},
            grid=both,
            major grid style={dotted},  
            minor grid style={dotted},  
            minor x tick num=1,
            minor y tick num=1,
        ]
            % ~~~ your approach ~~~~~~~
            \node at (85, -65) {dB};
            
            % ~~~ using the axis' coordinate system ~~~~~~~
            \node[teal] at (axis cs:270,45) {X};
            \node[blue] at (axis cs:0,0) {X};
            
            \addplot [no markers, 
                      thick, red] table [col sep=comma, y=Axial] 
                      {datap.dat};
%            \addlegendentry{2.40 GHz}
            % ~~~ simple, but intermingled with your shifts above ~~~
            \node[teal] at (axis cs:260,63) {Y};
            
            % ~~~ can we use the named entity for good? ~~~~~~~~~~
            \node[pt] at (A) {A};
            \node[pt] at ([xshift=55mm]A) {B};% ?!, see transformation above
            
            % ~~~ marking the axis description area ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
            \node[red!80] at (axis description cs:0,0) {00};
            \node[red!80] at (axis description cs:1,0) {10};
            \node[red!80] at (axis description cs:0,1) {01};
            \node[red!80] at (axis description cs:1,1) {11};
            
            
        \end{axis}
        
        % ~~~ could have worked ... but doesn't ~~~~~~~~~~~
        \node[anchor=north west] at (current axis) {Test};

    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}

1. Compile without transformations
This is a kind of "correct view". I commented out the 4 transformation related lines in the axis options.
AXIS:

POLARAXIS

Obviously

with AXIS an empty frame is drawn
desciption axis (~ plotting area) 00 .. 11 is (almost) above
the y-axis with units is somewhere to the left
once again, your placement of "dB" in absolute coordinates may not be the best choice
in POLARAXIS the only reliable position seems to be the placement of teal Y in the systems polar coordinates

I suggest to read on first and read again wrt to all the circled, teal and blue characters I set to grasp the logic of cartesian to polar, as intended to be here.
2. Same, but WITH transformations applied
AXIS

POLARAXIS

Conclusions
(1) Giving the yticklabel a name, like a node,  yticklabel style={anchor=east, xshift=-4.75cm,name=A},% p.376 makes it accessible later. It seems to refer to the last value put (40), from where you recall B as shifted position later.
It's very likely that more problems will occur when having different ranges, different max/min settings etc. I.e. where B will be exactly may vary.
(2) Putting teal Y as a node inside the polar/axis environment may or may not be subjected to the same kind of problems.
(3) Refering to the "plot area" (00-01-11-01) via  \node[anchor=north west] at (current axis) {Test}; AFTER the polar/axis doesn't seem to be useful. I doubt the other options mentioned in "4.19 Alignment Options" will be useful, as the y-Axis is built differently, outside so to say.
Suggestion:
A valid alternative might be to show NO labeled y-axis AND to draw it e.g. by a dedicated \pic (see Tikz-manual) with better control.

You also may want to review this Q&A: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/715226/245790 .

Thank you for very compheresive guide
