To which entities can I anchor nodes in pgfplots?
I find it difficult to read from the pgfplots manual, which entities I can refer to, e.g. to anchor nodes with further information.
E.g. in the example below, what are some or all entities I can reference?
\documentclass[10pt,border=3mm,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        title=hello,
        xlabel=x,   
     ]
        \addplot[domain=-1:1]   {(x-.2)^3 + 1};
     
        \addplot[domain=-1:1]   {x+1.5};    
    \end{axis}  
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}



In a nutshell you can refer to, at least:

entities, you can name via name=
predefined entities, like current axis, current plot begin and current plot end

See examples below. Note that order and placement of nodes can be relevant, see e.g. the current plot ... examples. Note the varying style options used with the nodes. I suggest to look up further details in the pgfplots-manual.
% ~~~ 10.04.2024: Where can I name things like a node? ~~~~~~~~~

\documentclass[10pt,border=3mm,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        name=AX,                    % <<<
        title=hello,                % not here
        title style={name=TS},      % <<<
        xlabel=x,                   % not here
        xlabel style={name=XL},     % <<<
        ylabel=y,                   % not here
        ylabel style={name=YL},     % <<<
     ]
     \addplot[
        domain=-1:1,
        %name path=CRV, % needs fill between
        %name=AP,       % no
     ]{(x-.2)^3 + 1};
     
     \addplot[domain=-1:1,]{x+1.5};
    
    \end{axis}  
    
    % ~~~ current axis ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    \node[anchor=west,red,circle,draw]  at (current axis.east)  {CA}; 
    
    % ~~~ current plot ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    \node[red,circle,draw]              at (current plot begin) {CPb}; 
    \node[red,circle,draw]              at (current plot end)   {CPe}; 
    
    % ~~~ named axis, see above ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    \node[anchor=west,teal]     at (AX.south east)      {AX}; 
    \node[anchor=east,teal]     at (AX.north west)      {AX}; 
    \node[teal]                 at (AX.outer north west){AX}; 
    \node[teal]                 at (AX.origin)          {AXorg}; 
    \node[teal]                 at (AX.center)          {AXcnt}; 
    
    % ~~~ named styles ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    \node[anchor=west,purple,draw]  at (TS.east)    {TS}; 
    \node[anchor=west,purple,draw]  at (XL.east)    {XL}; 
    \node[anchor=west,purple,draw]  at (YL.east)    {YL}; 
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}



You may want to inspect an other application here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/730497/245790 .
